# tempusdominus 4 multiselect population

Tags: bootstrap-4, tempus-dominus-datetimepicker

I'm trying to get initialized my DateTimepicker with multiple Dates. I can initalized with a specific date but not with the multiple option.

```
var selectedDates = ["12/1/2019","11/1/2019"];
    $(function () {
                $('#holidayPicker').datetimepicker({
                    format: 'L',
                    allowMultidate: true,
                    multidateSeparator: ' ',
                    minDate: "<?php echo $startDate->format('Y-m-d');?>",
                    maxDate: "<?php echo $endDate->format('Y-m-d');?>",
                   //   setDate: [new Date(2019, 0, 4),new Date(2019, 0, 5)]
                    useCurrent: false,
                    //date: new Date(2019, 0, 4),
                    setDate: selectedDates,
                });
            });
```

What i have already tried:

- with setDate an a array of Dates and Strings
- with date and multiple Strings or multiple Dates as Strings
- directly over the value attribut of the input field

Does someone has an idea?

Comment: I dont think its supported, ive created a feature request https://github.com/tempusdominus/bootstrap-4/issues/226 . I am currently looking into the source code to see if I can find some sort of a hack

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to find a function in the source code that allows you to set the date directly. You have to access the datetimepicker object directly in order to use it.

Code snippet:

```
var $el = ('#your-element');
// Initialize datepicker.
$el.datetimepicker({
    inline: true,
    format: 'DD-MM-YYYY',
    allowMultidate: true,
    useCurrent: false // Prevents selection of current date
});

// Get the object directly from the data attribute.
// @see https://learn.jquery.com/jquery-ui/widget-factory/widget-method-invocation/
var prefill = ['01-15-2019', '01-16-2019'];
var plugin = $el.data('datetimepicker');
for(let i = 0; i < prefill.length; i++) {
    // Set the dates as active. You can optionally pass your own moment object as the first argument.
    plugin.date(prefill[i], i);
}
```

Comment: It throws a "TypeError: oldDate is undefined" error when the Clear button is clicked.

Comment: You'll have to debug that further yourself. Possibly it is missing some other setting.